# SQL: How to Remove record from CTE if another result set had record for that id

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

A part can be used in a service entry and if it was used then service entry part table will have a record of that.

In the following a part was never used in a service entry so I display the applicable part for the a system with default config. when the report is run, is the servicedate is between 10/1/2014 - 10/2/2014

```
Instrument  Part Number Part Description              Revision Number   Date    xNumber 
ICQ IA EP5  152970     RSH-Load Platform-Arm (Spring),   100     
ICQ IA EP6  152970     RSH-Load Platform-Arm (Spring),   100         
ICQ IA EP7  152970     RSH-Load Platform-Arm (Spring),   100
```

IN the following 10/1/2014 - 10/6/2014 part was used in a service entry for system 6 and 7 as there is a service date/time so I include the revision number from the service entry part table and since on system 5 it was not used I display default config from part table.

```
Instrument  Part Number Part Description              Revision Number   Date    xNumber 
ICQ IA EP5  152970     RSH-Load Platform-Arm (Spring),   100     
ICQ IA EP6  152970     RSH-Load Platform-Arm (Spring),   101            10/05/2014
ICQ IA EP7  152970     RSH-Load Platform-Arm (Spring),   101            10/05/2014
```

Now if I run the report with date ranges supplied to the query as 10/1/2014 - 10/14/2014, you can see system 6 had another service entry on 10/05. Since system 5 never had a service entry I still display the default revision number from part table.

```
 Instrument  Part Number    Part Description              Revision Number   Date    xNumber 
    ICQ IA EP5  152970     RSH-Load Platform-Arm (Spring),   100     
    ICQ IA EP6  152970     RSH-Load Platform-Arm (Spring),   101            10/05/2014
    ICQ IA EP6  152970     RSH-Load Platform-Arm (Spring),   101            10/10/2014
    ICQ IA EP7  152970     RSH-Load Platform-Arm (Spring),   101            10/05/2014
```

So I wrote the following CTE which basically gives me every part applicable on a system and its revision number from part table.

```
DECLARE @run_log TABLE(      
        [Instrument] nvarchar(max),       
        [SubSystem] NVARCHAR(max),      
        [AbbottPartNumber] NVARCHAR(max),       
        [RSLMSPartID] int,      
        [PartDescription] NVARCHAR(max),
        [PartRevisionNumber] NVARCHAR(max),
        --[ServiceEntryID] int,
        [Date] datetime,
        [TSBNumber] nvarchar (max),
        [CRNumber] nvarchar(max) 
        )   
insert  @run_log 
select DISTINCT
     System.SystemFullName as Instrument,
     Part.System as SubSystem,
     Part.ID as PartID,
     Part.PartDescription,
     Part.RevisionNumber as PartRevisionNumber,
     --NULL as ServiceEntryID,
     NULL as Date,
     NULL as TSBNumber,
     NULL as CRNumber
     from Part
     inner join InstrumentType on Part.InstrumentTypeID = InstrumentType.ID
     inner join SystemModule on SystemModule.InstrumentTypeID = Part.InstrumentTypeID
     inner join System on System.ID = SystemModule.SystemID
     WHERE System.PlatformID = 2 and Part.Active = 1 and InstrumentType.Active = 1
     and Part.ID = 152970
     and Part.ParentID > 0

 ;WITH RunLogs AS(       
        SELECT  *    
        FROM    @run_log r
 )
```

The following query returns part applicable on system if they have a record in the service entry part table. If I union the results from the CTE with this result set I am close to my desired report output but What I am trying to do is if a part has a record in the following query, I need to remove that part record from the CTE above

```
-- Parts Installed in Entries inlc Baseline and/or user selected
 select 
      System.SystemFullName as Instrument,
     Part.System as Subsystem, 
     Part.ID as PartID,
     Part.PartDescription,
     COALESCE(ServiceEntryPart.PartRevisionNumber,Part.RevisionNumber) AS PartRevisionNumber,
     --ServiceEntryPart.ServiceEntryID,
     ServiceEntry.ServiceDateTime as Date,
     ServiceEntry.TSBNumber,
     ServiceEntry.CRNumber
     from Part
     inner join ServiceEntryPart on ServiceEntryPart.PartID = Part.ID
     inner join ServiceEntry on ServiceEntry.ID = ServiceEntryPart.ServiceEntryID
     inner join systemmodule on ServiceEntryPart.SystemModuleID = SystemModule.ID
     inner join System on System.ID = SystemModule.SystemID
     cross apply
     dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(ServiceEntryPart.ServiceTypeIDs, N',') M2
     JOIN  dbo.SplitStrings_Moden('1', N',') P ON (M2.Item = P.Item   or '1'IS NULL)
     WHERE System.PlatformID = 2 and Part.Active = 1 
     and Part.ParentID > 0 AND Part.ID = 152970
```

**EDIT**

If I do UNION ALL, between the CTE and second query I get results as follows, which is very close to what I need but rows number 7 and 9 should not be displayed because they are from the CTE and I dont need them because those parts were used in a service entry-service entry part, essentialy parts which are returned in the second query, if they are referenced in the CTE, they need to be not inlcuded in the results.

```
Instrument  SubSystem   RSLMSPartID PartDescription PartRevisionNumber  Date    TSBNumber   CRNumber
ICQ IA EP00  -  Dallas  RSH 152970  Arm (Spring), Tray/Carrier Detect   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
ICQ IA EP1  -  Dallas   RSH 152970  Arm (Spring), Tray/Carrier Detect   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
ICQ IA EP2  -  Dallas   RSH 152970  Arm (Spring), Tray/Carrier Detect   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
ICQ IA EP3  -  Dallas   RSH 152970  Arm (Spring), Tray/Carrier Detect   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
ICQ IA EP4  -  Dallas   RSH 152970  Arm (Spring), Tray/Carrier Detect   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
ICQ IA EP5  -  Dallas   RSH 152970  Arm (Spring), Tray/Carrier Detect   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
ICQ IA EP6  -  Lake County  RSH 152970  Arm (Spring), Tray/Carrier Detect   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
ICQ IA EP6  -  Lake County  RSH 152970  Arm (Spring), Tray/Carrier Detect   NULL    2014-10-09 17:35:00.000 NULL    NULL
ICQ IA EP7  -  Wiesbaden    RSH 152970  Arm (Spring), Tray/Carrier Detect   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
ICQ IA EP7  -  Wiesbaden    RSH 152970  Arm (Spring), Tray/Carrier Detect   NULL    2014-10-09 17:10:00.000 NULL    NULL
ICQ IA EPTraining  -  Training  RSH 152970  Arm (Spring), Tray/Carrier Detect   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your query of records to exclude as another CTE and then use a WHERE NOT EXISTS() to exclude those records.

```
 ;WITH toExclude AS( 

     -- Parts Installed in Entries inlc Baseline and/or user selected  
     select System.SystemFullName as Instrument,
         Part.System as Subsystem, 
         Part.ID as PartID,
         Part.PartDescription,
         COALESCE(ServiceEntryPart.PartRevisionNumber,Part.RevisionNumber) AS PartRevisionNumber,
         --ServiceEntryPart.ServiceEntryID,
         ServiceEntry.ServiceDateTime as Date,
         ServiceEntry.TSBNumber,
         ServiceEntry.CRNumber
         from Part
         inner join ServiceEntryPart on ServiceEntryPart.PartID = Part.ID
         inner join ServiceEntry on ServiceEntry.ID = ServiceEntryPart.ServiceEntryID
         inner join systemmodule on ServiceEntryPart.SystemModuleID = SystemModule.ID
         inner join System on System.ID = SystemModule.SystemID
         cross apply
         dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(ServiceEntryPart.ServiceTypeIDs, N',') M2
         JOIN  dbo.SplitStrings_Moden('1', N',') P ON (M2.Item = P.Item   or '1'IS NULL)
         WHERE System.PlatformID = 2 and Part.Active = 1 
         and Part.ParentID > 0 AND Part.ID = 152970

 )
 , RunLogs AS(       
        SELECT  *    
        FROM    @run_log r
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( select * from toExclude e
                           where r.Instrument = e.Instrument
                           and r.Subsystem = e.Subsystem
                           -- continue for all identity columns
                         ) 
 )
 -- use your CTE here, e.g.
 select * from RunLogs;
```

You could achieve the same thing a few other ways, e.g. just add WHERE NOT EXISTS or appropriate joins to your main query.